# Include choices with no records in grouped queryset

Tags: django, group-by, django-queryset

I'm trying to make a query in django grouping by a field with choices. I wanna get all choices values, algo choices with no records in the database.

My model:

```py
CHOICES = (
  ('new', 'New'),
  ('in_process', 'In process'),
  ('finished', 'Finished')
)
class Task(models.Model):
  ...
  status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=CHOICES)
```

My current query is:

```py
qs = Task.objects\
  .values('status')\
  .annotate(total=models.Count('status'))
```

At this moment, I only have finished task in db, but I wanna get all choices values, with zero if it doesn't have records.

Any idea?

Comment: The DB backends (MySQL, PostgreSQL etc) are not aware of your ***choices***, hence the result. IMO, as the resulting queryset never exceeds 3 items (since you have only 3 choices), it's OK to handle in your code level.

Answer (score -2):

You can do this with:

`Task._meta.get_field('status').choices`

The choices on a model field are only enforced at the application (Python) level - the DB doesn't know what choices are available.